# Android: how to override DPI value for my application

Tags: android

I am trying to adapt my application to the hardware supplied by third-party vendor. The main thing causing troubles is wrong screen density value reported by the system. It thinks that DPI is about 300 while the real dpi is about 100. This cause my view items to be extremely small.

I don't want to fit manually all dimensions to that tablet and broke application appearance on other devices. So, how can I override (for my app only) the DPI value used to calculate the dimensions?

Comment: You could try using AndAR, which I helped develop. It is open source, and there is no limit to the amount of images your app can have.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible from within your app on a phone/tablet which is not rooted.

Comment: @faceman technically it's rooted, but I cant do anything that will affect other apps, e.g. change system-wide settings